# LDAP_add with PHP: Operations Error

Tags: php, active-directory, ldap

I am quite a noob in using LDAP (this is actually my first project) and I can't find an answer on google that can help me...
So my problem is: I'm trying to add a contact with php to an active directory on a windows 2003 server. I can connect to the server, and neither I have problems with ldap_bind.
But when I run the program I always get the Error:

Warning: ldap_add() [function.ldap-add]: Add: Operations error in (Blabla) on line bla

and the ldap_error also only says "Operations error"
which is pretty vague, so I don't even know if it's a problem with the server or with my code.
I saw some threads with similar problems where servers didn't allow anonymous access, but I even bind with an admin account and it still does not work.

My code looks a lot like this:

```
$ldapcon=ldap_connect("servername");

if($ldapcon) {
    $bind=ldap_bind($ldapcon,"Admin@domain.com", "somePassword");
    if($bind) {         
        //  create data...
        $info=array();
        $info["cn"][0]          = "Hans Mustermann";
        $info["sn"][0]          = "Mustermann";
        $info["givenName"][0]   = "Hans";
        $info["mail"][0]        = "MustermannH@firma.de";
        $info["objectclass"][0] = "top";
        $info["objectclass"][1] = "person";
        $info["objectclass"][2] = "organizationalPerson";
        $info["objectclass"][3] = "contact";
        $info["ou"][0]          = "Users";
        $info["ou"][1]          = "contact";

        // add Data...
        $r=ldap_add($ldapcon, "cn=Hans Mustermann, sn=Mustermann", $info)
            or die(ldap_error($ldapcon)); //error: operations error
    }
}
```

Are there some infos missing? is the code wrong? do i need some changes on the ad-settings? is it a problem with "remote-rights-setting" or whatever?
Am I just too stupid and blind to see the problem or is it a bigger thing that is not easy to fix?
Does someone of you have an idea?

Thanks a lot
Chillikarli

Comment: I think you should replace $ad with $ldapcon

Comment: Oh sorry, that was not the problem I just forgot to change it when pasting the code :/

Comment: ldap_bind and ldap_error also use the $ad variable, is this also a typo?

Comment: oh no. yes it is. I am not really concentrated anymore, as i am really tired of fixing this stupid problem. sorry. i hope i fixed all typos now

Comment: what is the exact error?

Comment: as i said: "Warning: ldap_add() [function.ldap-add]: Add: Operations error in (php file) on line 72". the ldap_error also only says "Operations Error". That's all I have. Is there any detailled log-file? I can't find anything in the server's ntds-dir

Answer (score -2):

Instead of the or die() condition you might try this

```
// add Data...
if(!(ldap_add($ldapcon, "cn=Hans Mustermann, sn=Mustermann", $info))) {
     echo "There is a problem to create the account\n";
     echo "Please contact your administrator !\n";
     echo "LDAP Error: ".ldap_error($ldapcon)."\n";
     exit;
}
ldap_unbind($ldapcon);
```

Comment: yes, maybe that looks a lot nicer for the user, but this still doesn't fix my problem as the actual error-message is the same and doesn't bring any further infos. the problem is that ldap_add doesn't work at all.

Comment: Can you add the record manually with all the info/fields set as they are in PHP?